# css: FlexBox inside FlexBox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have an issue with FlexBoxes - I want

- I want to divide the page a section into two parts (same height), e.g. 100px each
- One of these sections (2nd) I want to divide into three subsections (equal height) 100/3 = 33px

Code below results in:

- height of first section: 80px
- height of second section: 120px

Important: I know, that this can be realized without FlexBoxes - the real page / purpose is a bit different.

But I really want understand what I am doing wrong!

Code:

```css
body {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100% padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.vbox {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  display: -moz-box;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-align: stretch;
  display: box;
  box-orient: vertical;
  box-align: stretch;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%
}
.vbox > * {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -moz-box-flex: 0;
  box-flex: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  display: -moz-box;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-align: stretch;
  display: box;
  box-orient: horizontal;
  box-align: stretch;
}
.boxFlex {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  box-flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="vbox">
  <div id="a" class="boxFlex" style='background-color:#0f0'>Box A</div>
  <div id="b" class="boxFlex">
    <div class="vbox">
      <div id="b1" class="boxFlex" style='background-color:#600'>Box B1</div>
      <div id="b2" class="boxFlex" style='background-color:#900'>Box B2</div>
      <div id="b3" class="boxFlex" style='background-color:#C00'>Box B3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are using the old (2009) flexbox syntax, is there a reason? Here is an example using the newest syntax: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoWJNK

Comment: And also using Oriol's solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbpOXL

Comment: @Marcelo... no sepcial reason for using th old syntax (actually I was not aware.

Actually, your solution works on Chrome as well, while the solution from Oriol as problems with chrome. 

What would be your (and Oriols) suggestion: Avoid flexbox if a page should be able to work across browers? It seems that the implementations are not really aligned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.vbox {
  display: flex;          /* Flex container */
  flex-direction: column; /* Display children in a column */
  min-height: 100%;
}
.boxFlex {
  height: 0;              /* Set initial height to 0 */
  flex-grow: 1;           /* Distribute remaining space */
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.vbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.boxFlex {
  height: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="vbox">
  <div id="a" class="boxFlex" style='background-color:#0f0'>Box A</div>
  <div id="b" class="boxFlex">
    <div class="vbox">
      <div id="b1" class="boxFlex" style='background-color:#600'>Box B1</div>
      <div id="b2" class="boxFlex" style='background-color:#900'>Box B2</div>
      <div id="b3" class="boxFlex" style='background-color:#C00'>Box B3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the height of the boxes b1..b3 is than "0"... but should be 100/3 = 33 or 34

Comment: @Andreas It works on Firefox, but not on Chrome. To make it work on Chrome, you can remove a wrapper: [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fn9p273e/)

Comment: Thanks, I see... It works fine with firefox (I agree). But for the development point of view I would prefer something like "boxes inside boxes".
And actually I somehow cannot belief that this is not possible...

Comment: @Andreas IMO it's better not to use unnecessary wrappers, specially if that fixes Chrome's buggy implementation of flexbox. But if you prefer "boxes inside boxes", you can try absolute positioning: [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fn9p273e/1/).